# How to detect if an application leaks memory?

Tags: linux, memory-leaks

I have quite a complex system, with 30 applications running. One quite complex C++ application was leaking memory, and I think I fixed it.

What I've done so far is:

- I executed the application using [valgrind's memcheck](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html), and it detected no problems.
- I monitored the application using [htop](http://linux.die.net/man/1/htop), and I noticed that virtual and residual memory is not increasing
- I am planing to run [valgrind's massif](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/ms-manual.html) and see if it uses new memory

The question is, how can I make sure there are no leaks? I thought if virtual memory stopped increasing, then I could be sure there are no leaks. When I test my application, I trigger the loop where the memory is allocated and deallocated several times just to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

You can't be sure except you know exactly all the conditions under which the application will allocate new memory. If you can't induce all of these conditions neither valgrind nor htop will guarantee that your application doesn't leak memory under all circumstances.

Yet you should make at least sure that the application doesn't leak memory under normal conditions.

Comment: I do know conditions under which the application allocate memory, and of course, I trigger them to test the application. The question is what can I check to make sure there are no leaks?

Comment: You need to know the internal work flow of the application, especially when (some point in time or some other event) the allocated memory should have been freed again.

Comment: I do know the internal work flow of the application. I created it :) I also created unit and functional tests, but that wasn't enough to miss a memory leak.

Comment: If you tested all of these cases with every possible input using valgrind then you can be rather sure that there is no memory leak in your application.

Comment: valgrind is not going to report leaks, if you (for example) extend std::vector endlessly, since the application will nicely release that memory. Or some cases with smart pointers, where objects are released when app ends

Comment: Of course. It only reports memory allocated but not freed by the application. How is it supposed to know whether the application actually needs all of the vector elements or not? It can't. But you can check if the memory increases over time and if it is supposed to increase or not, and if by which amount. There is no magic tool that is able to read the mind of the developer.

Comment: If you got two shared_ptr objects, each holding other, then you also got memory leak, since they can not be destroyed, but the memory is released when the process ends. This is a bug - hard to detect. You said I should check if memory increases. So, what exactly and how to check?

Comment: I don't understand your problem. Create a few test cases where your application is supposed to allocate and free much memory and check if it behaves as expected. I can't know how it SHOULD behave but you should be able to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

If valgrind doesn't report leaks, there aren't leaks in the sense of memory areas that aren't accessible anymore (during the runs you checked). That doesn't mean that the program doesn't allocate memory, uses it and doesn't free it when it won't use it anymore (but it is still reachable). Think e.g. a the typical to-do stack, you place new items on top, work on the item on top and then push another one. Won't ever go back to the old ones so the memory used for them is wasted, but technically it isn't a leak.

What you can do is to monitor the memory usage by the process. If it steadily increases, you *might* have a problem there (either a bona fide leak, or some data structure that grows without need).

If this isn't really pressing, it might be cheaper in the long run just letting it be...

Comment: I do monitor memory usage by process with htop. After some time, it looks like all memories of this particular process (VIRT,RES,SHR) stabilize, and do not grow further. Can you explain better what exactly to monitor?

Comment: @BЈовић, if memory usage stabilizes, it should be OK.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use a tool called Valgrind. It is memory debugging, memory leak detection, and profiling tool for Linux and Mac OS X operating systems. Valgrind is a flexible program for debugging and profiling Linux executables.
follow steps..

Just install valgrind

To run...
./a.out arg1 arg2

Now how to Use this command line to turn on the detailed memory leak detector:
valgrind --leak-check=yes ./a.out arg1 arg2
valgrind --leak-check=yes /path/to/myapp arg1 arg2

Or
 You can also set logfile:
valgrind --log-file=output.file --leak-check=yes --tool=memcheck ./a.out arg1 arg2

You can check its log for error of memory leak...
cat output.file

Comment: I did that, but valgrind didn't report leaks.